# Existential type or type parameter bound failure

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, existential-type, type-bounds, bounded-quantification

I have an F-bounded type `Sys`:

```
trait Sys[S <: Sys[S]]
```

And some trait which take it as type parameter:

```
trait Foo[S <: Sys[S]]
```

Suppose I have a method to be invoked with a `Foo`:

```
def invoke[S <: Sys[S]](foo: Foo[S]) = ()
```

Suppose I have a model update type, and a sub-type which carries a `Foo`:

```
sealed trait Update
case class Opened[S <: Sys[S]](foo: Foo[S]) extends Update
```

A helper function to register a model observer:

```
def observe(pf: PartialFunction[Update, Unit]) = ()
```

---

Now the following fails:

```
observe {
  case Opened(foo) => invoke(foo)
}
```

with

```
<console>:16: error: inferred type arguments [Any] do not conform to method invoke's
                     type parameter bounds [S <: Sys[S]]
                case Opened(foo) => invoke(foo)
                                    ^
```

**How can I fix the partial function**, if `Sys`, `Foo`, `invoke`, `Update`, `Opened` and `observe` are given. It is allowed to add a value or type member to `Foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is casting:

```
observe {
  case Opened(foo) => invoke(foo.asInstanceOf[Foo[~] forSome { type ~ <: Sys[~] }])
}
```

Obviously this is horrible and not the preferred solution, so I am waiting for other answers.

Answer (score 1):

How about move type parameter for **Foo** trait to type variable:

```
trait Sys[S <: Sys[S]]
trait Foo { type S <: Sys[S] }

sealed trait Update
case class Opened(foo: Foo) extends Update

def invoke(foo: Foo) = ()
def observe(pf: PartialFunction[Update, Unit]) = ()

observe {
  case Opened(foo) => invoke(foo)
}
```

**Update:**

You are absolutely right. And for all new type substitution you need to define alias for move type parameter to body.

Type alias example:

```
trait Sys[S <: Sys[S]]
class A extends Sys[A]
class B extends Sys[B]

trait Foo { type S <: Sys[S] }
trait Boo { type S <: Sys[S] } 

object module_A{
  type Foo = com.company.Foo { type S <: A }
  type Boo = com.company.Boo { type S <: A }
}

def invoke(foo: module_A.Foo, boo: module_A.Boo) = ()
```

Comment: The problem is this becomes immediately tiresome, my whole API is based on a type constructor parameter. You soon have `def foo[S1 <: Sys[S1]](bar: Bar { type S = S1 }, baz: Baz { type S = S1 }): Gaga { type S = S1 }` etc.